# Is there an easy way to open hotmail from outlook?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, hotmail

I like the Outlook interface but use hotmail. Is there a way to read by hotmail messages from outlook?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [outlook connector](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HA102225181033.aspx)

Comment: +1 Works perfectly fine. In Windows 7 I believe it's part of Live Essentials (since they tore out much of the standard stuff)

Comment: Works in 2003 ----------------